# JMETER Beanshell ( java.lang.String ) not found in class

Tags: java, selenium, jmeter, beanshell

I am developing a Jmeter beanshell script to work with Selenium. I decided to use the beanshell sampler so i can use java and selenium commands not accessible in the WDS interface.

My code work fine except for some String inputs. Here is a sample (torn down to barebones):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
```

and i get this error

```
2017/03/31 13:43:21 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions; debug();  ChromeOptions options . . . '' : Error in method invocation: Method addArguments( java.lang.String ) not found in class'org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions'  2017/03/31 13:43:21 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.BeanShellSampler: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions; debug();  ChromeOptions options . . . '' : Error in method invocation: Method addArguments( java.lang.String ) not found in class'org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions'  201
```

I see this similar in some other commands like sendkeys.

Why is this command not taking my String? I can run the full script and the browser opens file so i know selenium is setup with jmeter. It is just certain commands that use Strings that do this.

Thanks 
J

Comment: how exactly did you add the Selenium classes to the JMeter classpath?

Comment: It will not work, unless you are mapping the selenium jars properly. I suggest you to use web driver sampler. Beanshell is not apt to get better performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your Selenium client libraries version you may not have this method taking single String as a parameter. Create a new [Beanshell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) with the following line:

```
log.info(javap(org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions));
```

And look into JMeter console: you will see [javap command](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/bshcommands.html#javap) printing out all the available methods for the [ChromeOptions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeOptions.html) class, for instance for my installation (I have WebDriver Sampler plugin) it outputs the following:

> Class class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions extends class java.lang.Object
>
> public boolean org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions.equals(java.lang.Object)
>
> public int org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions.hashCode()
>
> public void org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions.**addArguments(java.lang.String[])**
>
> public void org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions.**addArguments(java.util.List)**

If you use the same Selenium libraries version (2.52.0) as I do you should change this line:

```
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
```

to this one:

```
options.addArguments(new String[] {"start-maximized"});
```

And your script should start working as expected.

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article for more information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter tests.